# convert list to dot-separated string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to convert the code below to have a dot added between the numbers it puts out? I'm not trying to use an algorithm or foreign library. I'm trying to continue my python knowledge with the built-in modules first

```
print(list("".encode("utf-8")))
```

Comment: to make your question easier to understand, please edit your question with the output you get, and the output you would like to get.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code it prints

```
>>> list("".encode("utf-8"))
[240, 159, 152, 128]
```

First we want to convert integers to strings; you can do this using `map`. `map` returns a `map` object, so I cast it to list to make the output readable:

```
>>> list(map(str, "".encode("utf-8")))
['240', '159', '152', '128']
```

Now you could use `join` to join all elements together with a dot:

```
>>> '.'.join(map(str, "".encode("utf-8")))
'240.159.152.128'
```

Comment: I believe this is the answer I was looking for ¡gracias!